# Run a script with pause conditions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Maybe what I want is not even possible but lets see.
I need to run a Linux command line:

```
(cd /packages/test/import/lisbon.stuck;ls;cd) | while read f ; do
    mv /packages/test/import/lisbon.stuck/$f /packages/test/import/lisbon/
    sleep 0.2
done
```

What I need to do is to get a script that runs this command, but pause the script when the number of files in `/packages/test/import/lisbon/` reaches 1000 and return from the script when the number of files gets down to 100.
Is this possible at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "returns the script"? Do you mean "continues"? Or "restarts"? Is someone/something else also moving files around in there?

Answer (score 0):

After the `mv` command in your `while` loop, you could check how many files in `/packages/test/import/lisbon/`, if there are more than 1000, sleep a while, then check again, if then it is less than 100, continue to move more files into this directory.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to have the script that removes files from the directory you are watch to send `SIGSTOP` and `SIGSTOP` to your script to control the flow of files into the directory, but the following function is functional, if a bit inefficient.

```sh
block_until_emptier () {
    files=( /packages/test/import/lisbon/* )
    if (( ${#files[@]} > 1000 )); then
        while (( ${#files[@]} >100 )); do
            sleep 0.2
        done
    fi
}

while true ; do
    block_until_emptier /packages/test/import/lisbon
    for f in /packages/test/import/lisbon.stuck/*; do
        mv /packages/test/import/lisbon.stuck/$f /packages/test/import/lisbon/
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) could help you. You should consider [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en), which enables you to run some script when the directory changes!